# Trimming dictionaries

Tags: python

I'd like to know if there is a more simple/pythonic way to trim the "size/length" of a dictionary in python. If I have a dict with 10 key-value-pairs(elements) and I'd like to restrict the size to be 5. Is deleting elements in a loop the best solution *(order/identity does not matter)*

```
def _trim_search_results(self):

    MAX_RESULTS = 5

    # a big dict
    results_to_be_trimmed = {result_1 ... result_n}

    # dict with length MAX_RESULTS
    trimmed_results = {}

    for index, key in enumerate(results_to_be_trimmed):
        if index == MAX_RESULTS:
            break
        else:
            trimmed_results[key] = results_to_be_trimmed[key]

    results_to_be_trimmed = trimmed_results
```

I think there must be a better solution ...

Comment: no - order/identity does not matter

Comment: I am curious as to why you would want to do this. If you don't care which items get removed, why not remove them all? `results_to_be_trimmed = {}`

Comment: @Kevin: I just need 20 results of about 50.

Comment: @kevin have you ever heard of sampling? You do not filter based on the features, just random, or even the dictionary itself may have a order that a cut of end or top may solve the problem.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You could try

```
d = dict(d.items()[:MAX_RESULTS])
```

In Python 3:

```
d = dict(list(d.items())[:MAX_RESULTS])
```

Comment: `[:MAX_RESULTS` instead of `[0: MAX_RESULTS]`

Comment: That's what I've been looking for. Thanks!

Comment: In python3 you need to wrap the `dict.items()` with a list e.g.: `d = dict(list(d.items())[:MAX_RESULTS])`, else you will get a `TypeError: 'dict_items' object is not subscriptable`

Answer (score 6):

You can use `itertools.islice` on `dict.iteritems`.

`dict.iteritems()` returns an iterator in py2.x, you can slice that iterator using `itertools.islice` and pass it to `dict()` to get the new dict.

**Demo:**

```
>>> from itertools import islice
>>> d = dict.fromkeys(range(10))
>>> dict(islice(d.iteritems(), 5))
{0: None, 1: None, 2: None, 3: None, 4: None}
```

#### Timings:

```
>>> d = dict.fromkeys(range(100))
>>> %timeit from itertools import islice;dict(islice(d.iteritems(), 10)) #winner
10000 loops, best of 3: 10.7 us per loop
>>> %timeit dict(d.items()[0: 10])
100000 loops, best of 3: 10.9 us per loop

>>> d = dict.fromkeys(range(10**5))
>>> %timeit from itertools import islice;dict(islice(d.iteritems(), 1000)) #winner
1000 loops, best of 3: 106 us per loop
>>> %timeit dict(d.items()[0: 1000])
100 loops, best of 3: 20 ms per loop
```

Comment: +1 for the timing measurement. if we talk about 'us' what's about imports - do they kill the performance advantage? thank you for the effort!

Comment: Thanks! That's interesting. I will use your approach for large dicts.

Comment: Not sure it makes sense to time the import here - in real code, you only do the import once, however often you use islice

Comment: @Eric Totally agree, I included that only on OP's request.

Comment: You can shorten `islice(d.iteritems(), 0, 5)` to `islice(d.iteritems(), 5)`.

Comment: @flornquake Well thanks again, feel free to edit my answer.(I'll accept your update if it is helpful) ;)

Answer (score 2):

This returns the 1st 2 elements of 4 from a dictionary (in python 2.6)

```
elems = {'a': 2, 'b': 7, 'c': 3, 'd': 9}
dict((k, v) for k, v in elems.items() if k in elems.keys()[:2])
```

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
d = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'd': 4}
MAX_VALUES=2
d = {k: d[k] for k in d.keys()[:MAX_VALUES]}
```

Comment: To work with python3, it should be:
d = {k: d[k] for k in list(d.keys())[:MAX_VALUES]}

Answer (score 1):

Important point to note: The keys in the `dict` are not ordered so it is not deterministic which keys you will get when you trim it to a particular length.

In python 2.7+,

```
trimmed_results = {key : results_to_be_trimmed[key] 
                                            for key in in results_to_be_trimmed.keys()[0:4]}
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
d = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'd': 4}

d = {k: d[k] for k in list(d.keys())[:2]}
```

It didn't work for me if I didn't apply list towards `d.keys`. So, don't forget to do that.